# How to get the Activated Date and Closed Date of a child workitem from TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I want to get the Activated and Closed Date of a child workitem , i am using the below query :

```
{SELECT
[System.Id]
,[System.Links.LinkType]
,[System.WorkItemType]
,[System.Title]
,[System.AssignedTo]
,[System.CreatedDate]
,[System.ChangedDate]
,[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ClosedDate]
,[Microsoft.VSTS.Common.ActivatedDate]
FROM WorkItems Where [System.Id] = 27279
}
```

and i am collecting the result as below :

```
 var flatQuery = new Query(workItemStore, detailsWiql.ToString());
 var workitems = flatQuery.RunQuery();
 var dispItem = new DisplayWorkItem
                {

                                ChangedBy = workitems[0].ChangedBy,
                                CreatedDate =  workitems[0].CreatedDate,
                                WorkItemType = workitems[0].Type.Name,
                                ParentID = links[i].TargetId
                 };
                 displayItems.Add(dispItem);
```

The problem is while using the . operator i see a list where Activated date and Closed Date option is not available.

any suggestions where am i making a blunder?

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat tough to follow but if you are just looking for a specific or known workitem I.E. 27279; why run a query at all and just use GetWorkItem method in the WorkItemStore Object.

```
var wi = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(27279);
foreach(var link in wi.WorkItemLinks)
{
     if(link.LinkTypeEnd.Name == "Child")
     {
         var child = workItemStore.GetWorkItem(link.TargetID)
         child["Closed Date"]
     } 
}
```

Comment: BJHop is giving an implicit pointer here: only a bunch of fields are available as C# Property. You can access any fields with the workitem["field name or reference"] syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify workitem[0].Fields["System.ActivatedDate"].Value to get the data you aee after. Remember as well that the field could be unavailable or may not be set. A little bit of defensive programming and you are good to go.

You need to specify those fields as being returned by the query so that you do not need to do workitem[0].Open() to get the full work item. If you need to use .Open it will slow your code way down.

In addition you need to create a Work Item and Direct Links query. Easyest way to do this is to build the query you want in visual studio and then saveAs to the desktop.